# Ordering text fields by letters first before numbers for all characters

Tags: sql-server, sorting, alphabetical

Ordering text fields by letters first before numbers for all characters

I am trying to order the below text fields show they come out in ascending order with letters coming first;

B054QL9
B05KY35
B9L57F0
BBQ2T21
BYZKJ27
0043823

The current code I have is;

```
SELECT
    i.tclstk
FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            tclstk
        FROM Figaro.dbo.tccclw WITH(NOLOCK)
        WHERE tclrqn = '6379'
            AND tclbgt = 'SPC'
            AND tclcom <> '0.00'
    ) i
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN LEFT(i.tclstk, 1) LIKE '[a-Z]' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
    ,i.tclstk
```

However what this does is it will only look at the first character and order them in alphabetical order from there, and then as per the above list it will order them numbers first for the remaining characters.

The order should be;

BBQ2T21
BYZKJ27
B05KY35
B054QL9
B9L57F0
0043823

The actual dataset being used is much larger than the above list so the above code would need to be amended to order all seven characters.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: If you're using SQL Server, as your title says (which it shouldn't as tags go in the tags, not the title), why have you also tagged [[tag:MySQL]]?

Comment: Why is `'BBQ2T21'` **before** `'BYZKJ27'` when the former has 3 alphas first and the latter 4? Can you elaborate on what the full logic is?

Comment: Apologies for the mistakes with the tags, first time i've posted in a long while. They need to be sorted by each character from left to right, so it will order on the 1st, then the 2nd then the 3rd etc. So BBQ2T21 will come before BYZKJ27 simply as the 2nd character is first alphabetically.

Comment: so you want normal sorting but letters are ahead of numbers? how long can this "thing" be in characters?

Comment: Yes correct, using order by would always put numbers are ahead of letters so asc or desc would give the wrong orders either way and i can't seem to work out how to amend the above code to get letters ahead of numbers for all characters. The strings will always be 7 characters long, this won't change.

Comment: Someone did post this answer and then deleted it. https://dbfiddle.uk/q5HhKBpx - not sure if they spotted a problem with it but seems to work as desired with your example values

Comment: Ah doesn't work with `nvarchar` though https://dbfiddle.uk/-1gX62u4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using SQL SERVER 2017+, you can use this to reverse the order of numerical and letters characters.

```
SELECT
    i.tclstk
FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            tclstk
        FROM Figaro.dbo.tccclw WITH(NOLOCK)
        WHERE tclrqn = '6379'
            AND tclbgt = 'SPC'
            AND tclcom <> '0.00'
    ) i
ORDER BY TRANSLATE(i.tclstk, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789', '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
    ,i.tclstk
```

Comment: I edit the answer, now will order `BBQ2T21` before `BYZKJ27`

Answer (score 0):

This is far from pretty, and honestly, I would suggest that perhaps you need to reconsider your data, but it "does the job".

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES('B054QL9'),
            ('B05KY35'),
            ('B9L57F0'),
            ('BBQ2T21'),
            ('BYZKJ27'),
            ('0043823'))V(YourString)
ORDER BY CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(V.YourString,1,1)) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
         SUBSTRING(V.YourString,1,1),
         CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(V.YourString,2,1)) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
         SUBSTRING(V.YourString,2,1),
         CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(V.YourString,3,1)) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
         SUBSTRING(V.YourString,3,1),
         CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(V.YourString,4,1)) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
         SUBSTRING(V.YourString,4,1),
         CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(V.YourString,5,1)) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
         SUBSTRING(V.YourString,5,1),
         CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(V.YourString,6,1)) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
         SUBSTRING(V.YourString,6,1),
         CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(V.YourString,7,1)) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
         SUBSTRING(V.YourString,7,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

My version:

```sql
select *
from (
    VALUES  (N'BBQ2T21')
    ,   (N'BYZKJ27')
    ,   (N'B05KY35')
    ,   (N'B054QL9')
    ,   (N'B9L57F0')
    ,   (N'0043823')
) t (col1)
order by replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(REPLACE(replace(cast(col1 as nvarchar(100)), N'0', nchar(64000)), N'1', nchar(64001)), N'2', nchar(64003)), N'3', nchar(64003)), N'4', nchar(64004)), N'5', nchar(64005)), N'6', nchar(64006)), N'7', nchar(64007)), N'8', nchar(64008)), N'9', nchar(64009))
```

What it does is to move the numbers to high plane unicode characters which *should* sort above the regular latin ones.

I wouldn't try this at home though, and i think you should avoid this kind of sorting if possible